# How to multiply lists of words like vectors?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have lists of words like this (only 2 listed here):

```
list_1 = ['average', 'reasonable'] 
list_2 = ['fiddle', 'frolic']
list_n = ['etc', 'etc']
```

I wish to multiply these two lists together to obtain this answer:

```
obj[l1] * obj[l2] = ['average fiddle', 'average frolic', 'reasonable fiddle', 'reasnable frolic']
obj[l1] * obj[l2] *...* obj[n]
```

I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
obj = {}
obj['l1'] = np.array(list_1)
obj['l2'] = np.array(list_2)
print(obj['l1']*obj['l2'])
```

But that only gives me an error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U10') dtype('<U10') dtype('<U10')
```

What do I do?

EDIT:
Tried using itertools like the user below suggested:

```
word_list = ['fair play']
output = {'fair': ['average', 'reasonable'], 'play': ['fiddle', 'frolic']}
result = []
for words in word_list: 
    for word in word_tokenize(words): 
        list_1 = output_set[word]
        result = [(x, y) for x, y in product(list_1, result)]
        result = list(map(' '.join, result))
print(result)
```

But this only returns an empty set. Is there a way to iterate through 'infinite' lists?

Comment: Isn't numpy array multiplication element-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *itertools.product* we could obtain these as `tuples` and then use `' '.join` to create `str`'s

```
from itertools import product

list_1 = ['average', 'reasonable'] 
list_2 = ['fiddle', 'frolic']
list_n = ['etc', 'vash']

a = [(x, y, z) for x, y, z in product(list_1, list_2, list_n)]
a = list(map(' '.join, a))
# ['average fiddle etc', 'average fiddle vash', 'average frolic etc', 'average frolic vash', 'reasonable fiddle etc', 'reasonable fiddle vash', 'reasonable frolic etc', 'reasonable frolic vash']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it with lists:

```
In [86]: list_1 = ['average', 'reasonable'] 
    ...: list_2 = ['fiddle', 'frolic']
In [87]: arr1 = np.array(list_1, object)
In [88]: arr2 = np.array(list_2, object)
In [89]: np.add.outer(arr1, arr2)
Out[89]: 
array([['averagefiddle', 'averagefrolic'],
       ['reasonablefiddle', 'reasonablefrolic']], dtype=object)
```

By making object arrays, as opposed to string dtype, I'm forcing the `add` ufunc to use the `+` method of Python strings.  As @Sandeep's answer shows, string addition is a join.  String multiplication is a replicate.

And with a 3rd array:

```
In [90]: arr3 = np.array(['etc', 'etc'], object)
In [91]: np.add.outer(np.add.outer(arr1, arr2),arr3)
Out[91]: 
array([[['averagefiddleetc', 'averagefiddleetc'],
        ['averagefrolicetc', 'averagefrolicetc']],

       [['reasonablefiddleetc', 'reasonablefiddleetc'],
        ['reasonablefrolicetc', 'reasonablefrolicetc']]], dtype=object)
```

I'm making a guess as to what you mean by chaining the operations.

Personally I prefer @vash's itertools solution; `numpy` doesn't add much to Python's string processing.

```
In [105]: [' '.join(x) for x in itertools.product(arr1,arr2,arr3)]
Out[105]: 
['average fiddle etc',
 'average fiddle etc',
 'average frolic etc',
 'average frolic etc',
 'reasonable fiddle etc',
 'reasonable fiddle etc',
 'reasonable frolic etc',
 'reasonable frolic etc']
```

Comment: I'll let you figure out how to add spaces :)  Normally we get spaces between strings with `join`.  `' '.join(['one', 'two'])`.  You don't get spaces with `'one'+'two'`, or with `'one'*2`.

Comment: thank you for comment, I like your list comprehension line you used with it, going to remember that